# How can I make a <select> take the size of its content?

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have the following markup:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        <select>
            <option>Very looooooooooooooooooooong value</option>
            <option>Some</option>
            <option>other</option>
            <option>value</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

​To which the following CSS styles are applied:

```
.foo, .bar {
    position: absolute;
}

.foo .bar select {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

My intent here is that the `<select>` takes, at least, the size of its content.

On Firefox, it works. On Chrome, it doesn't.

If I remove one of the two `absolute` positioning styles on the enclosing `<div>` it works.

This looks like a Chrome bug but I can't know for sure.

In my case, the two parents *must* have `absolute` positioning so removing that is unfortunately not an option. Do you know any workaround?

The jsfiddle demonstrating the issue is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arb54/).

​

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want it to be the size of the selected item, or of the longest available value?

Comment: @PhonicUK: The size of the longest available value. As Firefox does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify a width on .bar it will allow for some flexibility [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arb54/1/)

Alternatively you can remove position:absolute from .bar [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Arb54/4/)

Comment: Actually, it seems to work if I set one on .foo which is perfect in my case :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set the `min-width` to auto. I tested your fiddle on Chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
foo .bar select {
min-width: 100px;
}
```

you will get your output.Its not require.No need to give any width rather its fix or auto

Answer (score 0):

The `min-width` is the problem. Remove it and will work on Firefox and Chrome.